# TextField that only takes decimal number

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use the `inputFormatters` attribute to restrict input to a decimal number. The way to do that seems to be a regex string, however, it doesn't allow any input for some reason. If I just have a dot as regular expression, it works fine, but there's something about the complexity of the string that breaks functionality. Here's my code:

```
  TextField(
       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
       maxLines: 1,
       maxLength: 8,
       inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("/^(0|[1-9]\\d*)(\\.\\d+)?\$/"))],
       onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                                  valoare = value;
                                })
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the inputFormatters: are apparently running on each keystroke, even on partial input (input so far).

So to enter 123.45 (which is valid), you must go through a step that where the value is "123.", but that's invalid, and now you're toast.  Move your validation instead to the "validate:" method, which is called only when the input is complete.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm not sure what "validate" method you're referring to. It doesn't seem to be part of  the TextField object. Can you suggest an implementation?

Comment: It's part of making that a FormField.  And sorry, it's validator not validate: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/validator.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use options with keyboard type

like

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true,signed: false),
```

Comment: This allows all characters, for some reason.